# fail to install ionic signed app on android 11

Tags: android, ionic-framework, installation, sign, android-11

I can install my release version of my app on all of android versions except android 11.

I've followed [these](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html) instructions to sign my app.

Using [this tool](https://appetize.io) warns me that the .apk file is not signed.

I already tried checking not signed version of my app, and it works just fine in android 11.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am facing some issue.

Comment: Yeah, sign your app in android studio using v2 signature scheme @ShriHans

Comment: I had tried signing it, but it hadn't worked for me. Let me try again. 
1. Did you use JKS keystore or PKCS12? 
2. Is signing required even for debug version?

Answer (score 1):

hi guys i had the same issue and after spend many time i could fix it with 6 step.

Fixed ionic 6 application not installed on android 11

Step One: Install or Update some requirements

1. upgrade to Cordova version 10

   npm uninstall -g cordova

   npm install -g cordova@10.0.0
2. Upgrade android studio to latest version (android studio arctic fox)

> check this [link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/07/android-studio-arctic-fox-202031-stable.html) to know about android arctic fox and download it

1. install android build tools 30.0.2
2. install android sdk platform level 30
3. change some config on config.xml file

> ```
> <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="30" />
> <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
> <preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
> ```

and this is my complete answer at ionic [forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-application-not-installed-on-android-11/214997/6?u=alitalaee) so you can check it...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for it.
I couldn't find the v2 signing option in android studio but I used following commands to generate signed apk:

```
cordova build --prod --release android -- --packageType=apk

~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/31.0.0/zipalign -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk signed.apk

~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/31.0.0/apksigner sign --max-sdk-version=30 -ks my-release-key.keystore --ks-key-alias=alias_name signed.apk
```

Please change the path according to your OS. I am on mac.

If you are unable to install this apk on your device please make sure that no older version of same package is installed on your device.

Or please try to run below command before installing it:

```
adb uninstall <package name>
```

Above command will uninstall it cleanly from your device.

It worked for me after this.